# Hadamard quotient of D-finite series

Tags: formal-power-series

Here we work with the formal power series ring $K[[x]]$ where $K$ is a field of characteristic zero. The *Hadamard product* of two such power series is the coefficient wise product: thus if $f= \sum a_n x^n$ and $g = \sum b_n x^n$ are two power series then $f * g$ is defined to be
$$f* g := \sum a_n b_n x^n.$$
Notice that the function $(1-x)^{-1}$ is the identity for this operation. 
If the coefficients of $f$ are all nonzero, then it has a "Hadamard inverse" by taking the reciprocals of its coefficients and forming a new power series: 
$$\bar{f} := \sum \frac{1}{a_n} x^n.$$

Under Hadamard multiplication and usual addition, this is just the ring of sequences in $K$, which *a priori* has nothing to do with the usual product of power series. But here is the remarkable theorem on rationality of Hadamard quotients, connecting the Hadamard product to the usual product:

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $f ,g$ are rational power series with $g$ Hadamard-invertible, and $f*\bar{g}$ has coefficients in a finitely-generated ring. Then $f*\bar{g}$ is also rational.

This can be viewed as a rationality test: if all the coefficients lay in a finitely-generated ring (which is the case for a D-finite series), and you can write the coefficients as a quotient of two linear recurrences, then the power series is rational.

**I'm wondering if there is a similar Hadamard quotient theorem when "rational" is replaced by "D-finite".** A power series $f$ is *D-finite* if it satisfies a linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients; equivalently, its coefficient sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence whose coefficients are rational functions in $n$ (in which case $(a_n)$ is called *P-recursive*).

A quick google search finds a *conjecture* of Dimitrov, that if $f,g$ are D-finite with finite "height" and $f*\bar{g}$ also has finite height, then $f*\bar{g}$ is also D-finite. **What is known about this conjecture?** Unfortunately google and citation searches have not helped me.

Thanks!